# A closed degree symbol

Tags: math-mode, symbols

How can I make the exponent on gamma in this picture? The best description I can come up with is a closed degree symbol.

[image: gamma]

Answer (score 11):

```
$\gamma^\bullet$
```

Have a look at [“How to look up a math symbol?”](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-math-symbol) for ideas how you can easily find a particular symbol.

Comment: Thanks Caramdir--you never fail to impress me with your speed and consistency. also, that link was helpful for another thing I didn't know ($\trianglelefteq$)